# Unindenting multiline string literals

Tags: perl, cpan, multiline, code-formatting, literals

In Perl it is possible to write multiline string literals using ordinary quotes or here-doc statements, but because code indents are counted as the content of the string itself, this either ruins formatting of surrounding code, either requires us to additionally unindent string before using. At this point I use the following subroutine to unindent string literal:

```perl
sub unindent {
    local $_ = shift;
    $_ =~ s/^\s*$//mg;
    $_ =~ s/^(\s*>>>\s)//mg;
    return $_;
}

print unindent "
    >>> #pragma once
    >>> #include <...>
    >>> ";
```

But not to re-invent the wheel, I'd like to ask if there is already something for this purpose built-in into Perl or on CPAN?

Comment: It is not a good idea to use the global default variable `$_` inside a subroutine when its so easy to just create a lexical variable, e.g. `my $str = shift`.

Comment: or `local $_ = shift`.

Comment: @TLP, @tobyink, ops, I forgot that `$_` will not became local automatically. Thanks for your corrections!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more googling I've found some packages with similar features and partially solving the problem:

- [`Mojo::Util`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Mojo%3a%3aUtil)
- [`Filter::Undent`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Filter%3a%3aUndent)
- [`Filter::Indent::HereDoc`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Filter%3a%3aIndent%3a%3aHereDoc)
- [`Heredoc::Unindent`](http://jeremyholland.info/show_file.php?file=Unindent.pm) (not on CPAN for some reason)

The first option requires lots of dependencies to be installed (for simple `unindent` function), the rest three are for here-docs only. None of these packages seem to support additional markers (`>>>` in the question) which to my mind would be safer than plain indents (due to tab-space mixture problems).

Comment: I really like [Heredoc::Unindent](http://jeremyholland.info/show_file.php?file=Unindent.pm), but it only works for heredocs with a semicolon right after the identifier (e.g. `<<END;`) -- adjust it by replacing lines 56 and 70 with `[,;\)] # semicolon (end of statement) or comma (end of hash value) or bracket (the substr(<<END,0,-1) construct removes the last newline)`.

Comment: FWIW:  Source Filters are *strongly* discouraged in production code.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably less of an answer than a comment but due to no indenture in comments i figured using an answer would be way better to get my point across.
I reckon you look for a way to write something like

```
my $str= "Stuff One
          Stuff Two
          Stuff Three";
```

because it is more readable but the actual string should become:

```
my $str= "Stuff OneStuff TwoStuff Three";
```

or

```
my $str=
"Stuff One
Stuff Two
Stuff Three";
```

right? I do not know of a module to clean up the string and i believe it might not be trivial due to tabs or spaces used and should there be newlines or a newline after the last part? You could however just write:

```
my $str= "Stuff One".
         "Stuff Two".
         "Stuff Three";
```

or

```
my $str= "Stuff One\n".
         "Stuff Two\n".
         "Stuff Three";
```

and retain full control of what is and what is not part of your string without messing with code indenture or any unneeded dependencies.

Comment: It is quite obvious that `.` operator can be also used to form mutliline string, but having to quote every line makes a lot of visual noise. I the question I meant primarily the second case you mentioned, with newlines preserved, but it can be useful sometimes to have a variant of `unindent()` function which also removes line breaks.

Comment: Well, but you would have to remember which one does what. And more importantly, when someone reads your code, in my way they know immediately how the string will look and what is in it and what not. If you omit the quotes and points, anyone not familiar with the way the string is used some number of lines later will be quite confused. For me a string that looks like it was defined badly and where i had to check how it is used would interrupt me a lot more than a few quotes and points. Not to mention `unindent()` adds more individual characters than doing this for up to four lines.

Comment: And lastly, how does this add more visual noise than `>>>>`? Almost every programmer, have they ever seen Perl or not, will understand what the quotes and points do. But everybody except for you will be confused by what the `>>>>` do there.

Comment: @DeVader: Putting quotes (and "\n"!) for every line is very cumbersome and looks quite bad to me. Of course, `>>>` marker is very long, I didn't thought too much before picking it, but it can be safely replaced with, for example, `|`. I wish such a construct is built-in into the language itself.

Answer (score 1):

[You appear to want `Syntax::Feature::Qi`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Syntax::Feature::Qi). It's like Python's `textwrap.dedent`.

It's bizarre that there isn't something for this in the core language.